# sending multiple parameters through query string in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to send multiple parameters to a servlet named cart using this code.but it isending null.plz help.rs is a reference to resultset here

```
while(rs.next())
{
    String name=rs.getString("name");
    int cost=rs.getInt("cost");
    out.println("\n");
    out.println("Name: "+name);
    out.println("\nPrice: "+cost);
    out.println("\n<a href=\'cart\'?n=name&&c=cost>Add to Cart</a>");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it isending null"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the way the link is constructed.

This should work:

```
out.println("\n<a href='cart?n=" + name + "&amp;c=" + cost + "'>Add to Cart</a>");
```

In addition, it may be necessary to URL encode the content of `name` if it can contain characters with special meaning in an URL.

Comment: In addition, depending on the contents of name, you might want to URL encode it.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes, I will add that to the answer.

Comment: hey henry,it is giving syntax error which i could not resolve.